# Naruto self insert fanfic where they were born as Naruto’s son and twin brother of Himawari

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, naruto

I couldn't find a story that I read a year ago. It's on fanfiction.net. It was a self insert story. The self insert was born as Naruto's son and was the twin brother of Himawari. I don't remember it much but I can tell that in the end Himawari was kidnapped. The self insert also went to train with Sasuke along with Kakashi.

I couldn't recall the main character’s name and the story name either.

Comment: Was it an actual self-insert (i.e. meant to represent the author) or just an original character?